# help with funky function definition

Tags: functions

I've never encountered a function definition like this before and am wondering how you would go from this definition to finding out what features it has (y-intercept, even/oddness, min/max value, periodicity).

Definition for $f$

If the remainder of $x$ divided by 3 is 0, then $f(x)=11$.

If the remainder of $x$ divided by 3 is 1, then $f(x)=−7$.

If the remainder of $x$ divided by 3 is 2, then $f(x)=2$.

Comment: Try to calculate $f(3n)$, $f(3n+1)$, and $f(3n+2)$ for any integer $n$.

Comment: Have you tried some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that function is defined over set of Natural number N (as otherwise definition doesn't make much sense). You can look at its various properties viz. maxima is 11 (occurs at x : x=0(mod3)), and minima is -7 (occurs at x:x=1(mod 3)). You can check that function is neither even nor odd look at f(5) and f(-5). function is periodic with period 3 (verify !). and by y-intercept if you mean f(0) then you can see y-intercept=f(0)=11.

Comment: Hem, $f(0)=11$.

Comment: @Yves Daoust :ohh..yeah. I am sorry for making that mistake.Indeed f(0)=11. Thanks for correcting me. I will edit it.